# Does ReentrantReadWriteLock read while writeLock locked?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reentrantreadwritelock

I research `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

I write simple code for test(I know that use Thread.sleep() can not guarantee predictable result but I think that I am lucky:)):

```
public class RWLock {
    private static String val = "old";
    private static ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private static long time =  System.currentTimeMillis();
    public void read() {
        try {
            lock.readLock().lock();
            System.out.println("read " + val +" - "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void write() {
        try {
            lock.writeLock().lock();
            val = "new";
            System.out.println("write " + val+" - "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}

class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        new MyThreadRead().start();

        Thread.sleep(400);
        new MyThreadWrite().start();
    }

}

class MyThreadRead extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new RWLock().read();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyThreadWrite extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new RWLock().write();
    }
}
```

output:

```
read old - 0
write new - 401
read new - 10401
read new - 10902
read new - 11402
read new - 11902
read new - 12402
read new - 12902
read new - 13402
read new - 13902
read new - 14402
```

10401 - 401 == 10000

10000 it is time of writing.

As I understood second read thread cannot finish before writing. Thus writing and second reading performs in parallel. It is not predictable behaviour for me.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have more sleep() calls than you realize.  The sleep calls in MyThreadRead#run() and in RWLock()#read() add up to 500 ms.  So here's what's happening.

```
At T=0, the reader thread grabs the read lock and sleeps for 300ms.
At T=300, the reader releases the lock, and then sleeps for another 200ms.
At T=400, the writer grabs the write lock and sleeps for ten seconds,
At T=500, the reader tries to grab the read lock, but it is blocked by the writer.
At T=10400, the writer gives up the lock, and then the reader gets to go round
   its loop nine more times.
```

---

P.S.:  Move your lock() calls out of the try/finally statements.  E.g.,

```
...lock()
try {
    ...
} finally {
    ...unlock();
}
```

That way, if the lock() call throws an exception, the unlock() will not be called.